# MQTT backend scaling

Tags: load-balancing, scalability, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I am currently developing a typical IoT service. At the moment multiple devices connect to one MQTT broker (mosquitto) and my java backend also connects to the broker (Paho).

The problem i see is the following:
When i am going to have multiple instances of my java backend every backend will receive and process every message received. That`s a big issue. I just want to deliver a message to only one java backend. Anybody an idea how to deal with this problem?

Btw: Java backends will be added or removed depending on the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options

1. Place a queuing system between your application and the MQTT broker, possibly something like Apache Kafka
2. HiveMQ and IBM MessageSight brokers support (different implementations) of something called shared subscriptions. This allows messages to be shared out between more than one client. Shared subscriptions is likely to be formally added to the MQTTv5 spec which should mean that it will be added to more broker and have a standard implementation.

Comment: Thanks very much! I think the second option will be very usefull